# Trying to display current size of a ref element in a nested component with React.forwardRef() - it's always showing previous result

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, react-forwardref

I need to make a styled-component div with button, button generates size of the div. Then a component nested inside of the div component displays the size. It has to use forwardRef and both components have to be functional.

Base component code:

```
const StyledComp = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 100, height: 100 });
  const [maxMin, setMaxMin] = useState({ max: 500, min: 100 });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  let ref = useRef(<Shape />);

  const handleResize = () => {
    const max = maxMin.max;
    const min = maxMin.min;
    let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    let height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    setSize({ width, height });
    setCount(count+1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="styled-component">
      <Shape height={size.height} width={size.width} ref={ref}>
        <ShapeResult count={count} {...{ ref }} />
      </Shape>
      <p>Width: {size.width}</p>
      <p>Height: {size.height}</p>
      <button onClick={handleResize}>Generate</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The  component is a simple styled-components div with width and height from props.
The  gets the ref just fine, I can print it in console and it does show the current size of the element. But when I try to get the width/height values via innerRef.current.offsetWidth it gets previous generation results. Here's the  code:

```
const ShapeResult = ({ count }, ref) => {
  let innerRef = React.useRef(ref);
  const [countState, setCountState] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
  useEffect(() => {
    innerRef = ref;
    console.log(innerRef.current);
    setWidth(innerRef.current.offsetWidth);
    setHeight(innerRef.current.offsetHeight);
    setCountState(count);
  }, [count, ref]);

  return (
    <div className="shape-result">
      <p>Click count: {countState}</p>
      <p>Width: {width}px</p>
      <p>Height: {height}px</p>
    </div>
  );
};
const ForwardedResult = React.forwardRef(ShapeResult);
export default ForwardedResult;
```

I'll be grateful for any help, I've been searching for an answer for way too long and it really shouldn't be that hard task...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the main problem was in the useEffect. It should be:

```
setWidth(innerRef.current.getAttribute("width"));
setHeight(innerRef.current.getAttribute("height"));
```

It finally updates now

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems incorrect.

As shown below, in the `StyledComp` component, access DOM through `shapeResultForwardRef.current`.

```
const StyledComp = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 100, height: 100 });
  const [maxMin, setMaxMin] = useState({ max: 500, min: 100 });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  let ref = useRef(<Shape />);
  const shapeResultForwardRef = useRef(null); // add


  const handleResize = () => {
    const max = maxMin.max;
    const min = maxMin.min;
    let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    let height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    setSize({ width, height });
    setCount(count+1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="styled-component">
      <Shape height={size.height} width={size.width} ref={ref}>
        <ShapeResult count={count} ref={shapeResultForwardRef} />
      </Shape>
      <p>Width: {size.width}</p>
      <p>Height: {size.height}</p>
      <button onClick={handleResize}>Generate</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

another：

```
const ShapeResult = ({ count }, ref) => {

  return (
    <div className="shape-result" ref={ref}>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
const ForwardedResult = React.forwardRef(ShapeResult);
export default ForwardedResult;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though, the displayed width and height in the ShapeResult should be those of the <Shape> component. The task is to pass the ref of <Shape> to <ShapeResult> and display the data there.